# error in installing packages in R studio :it shows unable to install packages

Tags: r

[image]

Please see error in image error and anyone familiar with R studio solve the error as soon as possible.

Comment: What version of R do you have? Use the `version` function to check whether the package is compatible with your current R version.

Comment: Rstudio does have some problems occasionally with packages installations, with multiple different versions of R, I would try installing the package through the R console instead. that usually solves these problems for me, if the package is indeed compatible with your R version

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it will work

```
.libPaths("")
dir.create("packages")
.libPaths("packages")
install.packages("sqldf")
```